# Total internal reflection of sound

Tags: waves, acoustics, reflection

Does sound experience the total internal reflection from a boundary of two materials, say, aluminum and copper? The Freshnel formulas for light depend on polarization. However, sound typically is not a transverse wave. How can the critical angle be estimated?

Comment: The difference in acoustic impedances would determine the degree of reflection.

Comment: For impedance:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_impedance

Comment: For reflection: https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Ultrasonics/Physics/reflectiontransmission.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in acoustic impedances would determine the degree of reflection.

For impedance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_impedance

For reflection: https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Ultrasonics/Physics/reflectiontransmission.htm